# Faster alternative methods to for-loop in R for pattern matching

Tags: r, plyr, apply

I am working on a problem in which I have to two data frames data and abbreviations and I would like to replace all the abbreviations present in data to their respective full forms. Till now I was using `for-loops` in the following manner

```
abb <- c()
for(i in 1:length(data$text)){
  for(j in 1:length(AbbreviationList$Abb)){
    abb <- paste("(\\b", AbbreviationList$Abb[j], "\\b)", sep="")
    data$text[i] <- gsub(abb, AbbreviationList$Fullform[j], tolower(data$text[i]))
  }
}
```

The abbreviation data frame looks something like the image below and can be generated using the following code

[image]

```
Abbreviation <- c(c("hru", "how are you"), 
                  c("asap", "as soon as possible"), 
                  c("bf", "boyfriend"), 
                  c("ur", "your"), 
                  c("u", "you"),
                  c("afk", "away from keyboard"))
Abbreviation <- data.frame(matrix(Abbreviation, ncol=2, byrow=T), row.names=NULL)
```

names(Abbreviation) <- c("abb","Fullform")

And the data is merely a data frame with 1 columns having text strings in each rows which can also be generated using the following code.

[image]

```
data <- data.frame(unlist(c("its good to see you, hru doing?", 
                            "I am near bridge come ASAP",
                            "Can u tell me the method u used for",
                            "afk so couldn't respond to ur mails",
                            "asmof I dont know who is your bf?")))
names(data) <- "text"
```

Initially, I had data frame with around 1000 observations and abbreviation of around 100. So, I was able to run the analysis. But now the data has increased to almost 50000 and I am facing difficulty in processing it as there are two `for-loops` which makes the process very slow. Can you suggest some better alternatives to `for-loop` and explain with an example how to use it in this situation. If this problem can be solved faster via vectorization method then please suggest how to do that as well.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: By "example" I mean something that I can cut and paste to my R to check my answer, and not a screenshot that I would have to retype manually :-)

Comment: Use `dput(head(AbbreviationList))` for example

Comment: @January Kindly check the updated description

Comment: @Ankit OK, I found a bug in my answer, but now it works. Note when testing that in your original script you had "AbbreviationList" and "Abb", but in the example you used "Abbreviation" and "abb" (and I also used the latter forms).

Comment: @January Sorry about that, as I have created the data generation code for you guys only so some typo mistakes...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, clearly there is no need to compile the regular expressions with each iteration of the loop. Also, there is no need to actually loop over `data$text`: in R, very often you can use a vector where a value could do -- and R will go through all the elements of the vector and return a vector of the same length.

```
Abbreviation$regex <- sprintf( "(\\b%s\\b)", Abbreviation$abb )

for( j in 1:length( Abbreviation$abb ) ) {
    data$text <- gsub( Abbreviation$regex[j], 
                       Abbreviation$Fullform[j], data$text,
                       ignore.case= T )
 }
```

The above code works with the example data.

Comment: This definitely reduces one for loop. Is it possible to replace the other one with apply function?

Comment: I have tried the following code but it is giving not eh desired result any idea where the fault may be.

**lapply(Abbreviation$abb, function(x){data$text <- gsub(Abbreviation$regex[Abbreviation$abb==x], Abbreviation$Fullform[Abbreviation$abb==x],data$text,ignore.case= T)})**

Comment: Simply: within the function closure (`function(x){ ... }`) you cannot modify `data`. Use a `for` loop, it will not be slower than lapply in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This should be faster, and without side effect.

```
mapply(function(x,y){
  abb <- paste0("(\\b", x, "\\b)")
  gsub(abb, y, tolower(data$text))
},abriv$Abb,abriv$Fullform)
```

1. `gsub` is vectorized so no you give it a character vector where matches are sought. Here I give it data$text
2. I use `mapply` to avoid the side effect of `for`.

Comment: This looks good but it creates a matrix of `nrows(data) x nrows(Abbreviations)`. But is there any way I can convert it to a `nrow(data) x 1` matrix

Comment: @Ankit You should Create a reproducible example with the desired output.

Comment: Actually, as I have mentioned that I would like to replace the abbreviations with their full form. So, I would like to get the output with same dimensions as that of input data.